# ¿Como puedo evitar que el console.log() tenga un salto de linea en nodejs?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Necesito imprimir por la consola este tipo de patrón:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Tengo listo la solución pero no se como evitar que el console.log realice un salto de linea

Le muestro la solución que estoy implementando

```
    for (var i = 0; i < numero; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            console.log('*')
        }
}
```

Estuve buscando algún método asociado a console.log que evite el salto de linea pero no logre conseguir nada

Answer (score 4, accepted):

console.log siempre imprimirá en la consola una línea con retorno de carro. Si lo que quieres es obtener ese patrón, simplemente tienes que ir añadiendo asteriscos a la línea e imprimirla cuando el patrón esté completo. Te dejo un ejemplo, la variable numero contiene el máximo de asteriscos de la línea mayor.

```js
var numero = 5;
for (var i = 1; i < numero + 1; i++) {
    var linea = "";
    for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        linea += "*";
    }
    console.log(linea);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo mismo que la respuesta anterior pero con un solo while.

```
const levels = 8

let i = 0
let asteriscos = ''
while (i <= levels) {
    asteriscos = asteriscos + '*'
    console.log(asteriscos) // '***'
    i++
}
``
```

Answer (score 0):

Si estás en `node`, para evitar el salto de línea puedes usar la función:

```
process.stdout.write("*");
```

Tu código quedaría:

```
var numero = 5;

for (var i = 0; i < numero; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
        process.stdout.write("*");
    }
    process.stdout.write("\n");
}
```

Dando como salida:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```